# Strategy for count when doing pagination

Tags: java, sql, jpa, pagination, jmesa

I´ve a table that holds about 40 million records.
I´m doing the pagination of that table with an offset of 10 record per page.
The problem is i´ve got to show the total number of records and the number of pages (given certain criteria).
That SELECT COUNT is taking too long to process, about 20 secs.
I´ve got a timeout hint but his is not solving the problem, and the database (table) is growing...

Anyone got this problem? What was the solutions that you implement?

I´ve got indexes and the query is tunned, the problem is the number of records...

I´m using hibernate JPA, JAVA and jMesa for the pages show with pagination.

Cheers,

Comment: Maybe a view that saves the table's count?

Comment: don't show it.  Show ellipses (...), or set up an async process and show it when it eventually returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle database and if an approximation of the number of rows in the table is sufficient, try:

`SELECT NUM_ROWS FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE';`

Another alternative is:

`SELECT COUNT(*) * 100 FROM YOUR_TABLE SAMPLE BLOCK (1);`

Addendum:

SQLServer equivalent for the first query:

`SELECT rows FROM sys.sysindexes
 WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('YOUR_TABLE') AND indid < 2`

Comment: I´m using SQL Server and i don´t believe this is possible using JPA.

Comment: I don't see why you can't access catalog tables using JPA.

Comment: Ok, i can do that, if i want to have the table metadata. I don´t, what i want is the table count base in certain criteria (business criteria), based in the resident data inside the table. Something like this: SELECT count(PK) from table where name = 'example'.